# 301 Redirect [nginx]: redirecting only on 1 of 2 servers with same configurations, both need to redirect

Tags: nginx, https, http-status-code-301

We have an issue with one of our servers not redirecting to "HTTPS".
Tried different browsers, computers in an outside network, removing cache, stopping Nginx, restarting Nginx, testing if Nginx is running correctly, making sure there are no default files still in Nginx config folders. The only other thing I haven't tested is if old process are running and I am doing that now.
This is running correctly on one of our servers but the other it gives an error.

This site can’t be reached

[omitted info] took too long to respond.
Search Google for [omitted info]
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Running Ubuntu 16
Nginx

our config file:

```
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    # listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name [omitted info];

    ssl_certificate     [omitted info];
    ssl_certificate_key [omitted info];

    location ~ ^/(assets/|images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
        root [omitted info];
        access_log off;
        expires 24h;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:[omitted info]/;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

  }
```

Here is what we tried:

$ nginx -t

results:

```
    nginx: the configuration file [omitted info]/nginx.conf syntax is ok
    nginx: configuration file [omitted info]/nginx.conf test is successful
```

$ curl -I -L https://[websiteURL].com

results:

```
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Server: [omitted info]
    Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 19:55:46 GMT
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 28
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Powered-By: [omitted info]
    Location: [omitted info]
    Vary: Accept

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: [omitted info]
    Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 19:55:46 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 4620
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Powered-By: [omitted info]
    ETag: [omitted info]
```

$ curl -I -L http://[websiteURL].com

results:

```
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Server: [omitted info]
    Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 20:12:07 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 194
    Connection: keep-alive
    Location: https://[websiteURL].com

    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Server: [omitted info]
    Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 20:12:07 GMT
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 28
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Powered-By: [omitted info]
    Location: /login
    Vary: Accept

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: [omitted info]
    Date: Sun, 21 May 2017 20:12:07 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 4620
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Powered-By: [omitted info]
    ETag: [omitted info]
```

Comment: Try changing your redirect block, please have a look at this link https://serverfault.com/a/337893

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, this didn't work. But I did add "add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";" to the server block.